# Determining vector space basis

Tags: vector-spaces

I am required to find the basis of : 
$$
M=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}m & m \\2m & 0 \end{bmatrix} : m \in\Bbb R\right\}
$$
Now I am aware of the process when I have two different elements of the matrix, (for example a and b), what I am interested in is how can I make multiple linearly independent vectors that correspond to this exact space ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, you aren't required to find **the** basis of $M$, but **a** basis. Secondly, I do not understand your question at all.

Comment: What makes you think the basis is necessarily composed of multiple vectors ?

Comment: Sorry if you couldn't understand. What I meant was, is it possible to find multiple linearly independent vectors that form the basis of M ?

Comment: Again, what makes you think the basis has to be composed of *multiple* vectors ?
What do you think is the dimension of M ?

Comment: well that's what bothers me. I couldn't make even two that are linearly independent.. so does it mean that dim(M)=1 ?

Comment: Yes, dim(M)=1. See the answer below. And a basis for a dimension 1 linear subspace is necessarily composed of only 1 vector. You can't find several linearly independant vectors in a space whose dimension is 1.

Comment: exactly what I needed to know. Thanks you sir.

Comment: You should check the  answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you notice that every matrix in this set if of the form $m\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$?  So every matrix is a multiple of $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

(Thanks, amsmath.)

Comment: Yes, and with that I can derive the answer easily. Thanks.